# Alignment of equations with conditions

Tags: alignment

I am trying to reproduce the image below [image]
and I have almost succeeded, but not quite.
Here's what I'm doing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    a           &= q_1b + r_1           &&0 < r_1 < b               \\
    b           &= q_2r_1 + r_2         &&0 < r_2 < r_1             \\
    r_1         &= q_3r_2 + r_3         &&0 < r_3 < r_2             \\
                &\hphantom{=} \vdots    &&\hphantom{0 < i} \vdots   \\
    r_{n-2}     &= q_n r_{n-1} + r_n    &&0 < r_n < r_{n-1}         \\
    r_{n-1}     &= q_{n+1} r_n + 0
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas how to do better? For one thing, I want the vertical dots to be exactly below the equal signs on the left and exactly below the r's on the right. Also, the space between the two alignments is too big.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you like this layout? I used  `alignat` which gives you  full control on the spacing between the columns of an aligned set of equations and the `\vdotswithin` command from mathtools (an extension of `amsmath`) to centre the left vdots w.r.t. the `=` sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
    a &= q_1b + r_1 &&0 < r_1 < b \\
    b &= q_2r_1 + r_2 &&0 < r_2 < r_1 \\
    r_1 &= q_3r_2 + r_3 &&0 < r_3 < r_2 \\
                &\vdotswithin{=}&&\hphantom{0 < i} \vdots \notag \\
    r_{n-2} &= q_n r_{n-1} + r_n &\qquad&0 < r_n < r_{n-1} \tag{$ n-1 $}\\
    r_{n-1} &= q_{n+1} r_n + 0 \tag{$ n $}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: :"to center the left vdots w.r.t. the = sign" what is the meaning of w.r.t?

Comment: @pzorba 75: par rapport à (‘with respect to`).